# How do pass parameters with the `send` function

Tags: ruby

I'm using cancan in a Rails 3.2 app, and in the abilities.rb classing have a method for each role's abilities

```
#ability.rb

def initialize(user)
  user_or_admin ||= User.new

  user.roles.each do |role| 
    send(role.name)
  end
end

def role_name_a

end

def role_name_b

end
```

Some of these methods require access to the user record, how do I pass it with the send function?

e.g. I want to do something like

`send(role.name)(user)`

and then

`def role_name_a(user)`

But this doesn't work. Grateful for any ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The arguments are the second parameter to `send`. The first argument is the method name as a symbol.

```
send :"#{role.name}", user
```

You should try looking at Ruby's documentation for questions like this. The language is well documented.

http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html#method-i-send

Comment: great, thanks for the reference, I was looking in the wrong place!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is best practice but it's what is in the cancan documentation.

```
def initialize(user)
  @user = user || User.new

  user.roles.each do |role| 
    send(role.name)
  end
end

def role_name_a
  can :manage, User, id: @user.id
end

def role_name_b

end
```